# Is there any way to differentiate Lifeline and Other elements in SYSML Sequence diagram through API or DB?

Tags: java, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram, sysml

I have Actor and Sequences as life lines in my sequence diagram in Enterprise Architect.

[image: Sequence Diagram with Fragment].

This diagram has a fragment also in it. I tried to fetch the diagram object through java API.

I'm able to get all the Actor, Sequence and Fragment information from the API. But I am unable to differentiate which among these are life lines.

Is there any way to differentiate Lifelines and other elements through API or through EA Database?

Little more hint about how to approach this problem would be more appreciated.

Code snippet that i'm using as follows
.
.

```
 Diagram sequenceDiagram = rep.GetDiagramByGuid(seqdiagGuid);
 Collection<DiagramObject> diagObjs = sequenceDiagram.GetDiagramObjects();
 for (DiagramObject obj : diagObjs) {
   Element el = rep.GetElementByID(obj.GetElementID());
   // How to differenciate whether this el is a lifeline?
 }
```

---

Edited with few more information and screen shots to give some more clarity

I have dropped a class from toolbox. While copying i selected the option as "Lifeline". For this newly added class, I am expecting el.type would give value as "LifeLine" but unfortunately it is giving "Object" only. Now my question is how this object can be identified as Lifeline of type Class?

[image: Class from toolbox]

[image: Selection of Lifeline]

[image: Added as Object rather than a Lifeline]

Hope this gives more clarity.

Comment: Can you post the code you have already? That would be useful in answering the question.

Comment: Looks like you are using a link (which EA sadly still allows). That would be wrong. You need to use instances. In your browser they woud appear either as object or lifeline icon (EA is a strange tool).

Comment: @GeertBellekens, I have updated my question with a code snippet. There i am unable to differentiate what kind of it is. type and metaType information of the element object is not helping here.

Comment: If you model your sequence diagrams correctly (not with links, but with real lifelines) you can use `el.Type` to differentiate between the different types of elements.

Comment: Can you please confirm what kind of element you are actually using? If it's a link to an actor rather than an instance you won't be able (and that's what you get from bad models).

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Thank you for the updates. I had selected Lifeline rather than Link. Even for this also I am not getting this information ( Lifeline of type Class) from API. For more clarification, i have edited my question  with few more screen shots.

Comment: I quickly tested this and lifelines from the toolbox have type "Sequence", whereas classes dropped as lifeline have type "Object". You can check the Classifier type by selecting the element based on the ClassifierID in the object/lifeline

Answer (score 1):

If you drop a class onto a sequence diagram *as a lifeline* you will effectively get an element of type Object, that is an instance of your class.

Using the `ClassifierID` you can then get the Classifier element

So starting from you sample

```
 Diagram sequenceDiagram = rep.GetDiagramByGuid(seqdiagGuid);
 Collection<DiagramObject> diagObjs = sequenceDiagram.GetDiagramObjects();
 for (DiagramObject obj : diagObjs) {
   Element el = rep.GetElementByID(obj.GetElementID());
   // How to differenciate whether this el is a lifeline?
   String elementType = el.GetType(); //this will be "Object" if you drop a class as a lifeline, and "Sequence" if you choose a lifeline from the toolbox
   if (el.GetClassifierID > 0) {
       Element classifier = rep.GetElementByID(el.GetClassifierID);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the good hint. I am very new to this EA and really sorry if my question is silly one. But still I have a Fragment also in my sequence diagram. I would like to mark somehow this Fragment is not a life lines like Actor and other classes in my sequence diagram. If i iterate all the diagram objects, I will be getting this fragment object also there.  Now i need to to mark Actor and Other classes in my sequence diagram are Lifelines but this Fragment is not.

Comment: You have to check the string elementType. It will read "InteractionFragment" for a fragment, and the el.classifierID will be 0.